# Streaming RTMP with an overlay, react-native

Tags: react-native, rtmp

I'm using https://github.com/NodeMedia/react-native-nodemediaclient to livestream to a server without issue, it's working as intended. But I'm wondering how I would go about if I wanted to send the camera feed with any type of overlay?

For example, livestreaming an football game and wanted to show a scoreboard or a clock to the user who is watching. Is this even possible?

Comment: Have you had any progress on this? I've been able to accomplish this by mutating the RTMP stream in transit to the CDN using FFmpeg but there's naturally a pretty considerable delay. I'd be glad to show you how I accomplished this if that's interesting to you.

Comment: @CristianHG That sounds very interesting and I'd be very happy to look into your work! Do you have a github link or something similar?

Comment: @CristianHG Bump :D

Comment: Any updates on this? :D